# Trying to implement a simple Flask-JS Server Connection

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server

When I run my server and my html file and I check the console, the consol for the html file keeps giving me `index.html:19 POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/receive-message 405 (Method Not Allowed)` For some reason, I cannot facilitate a connection between my JS and my Flask Server.

Here is the index.hml code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Flask and JavaScript App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Flask and JavaScript App</h1>
        <button id="sendButton">Send "hi" to Server</button>
        <p id="responseMessage"></p>

        <script>
            const sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
            const responseMessage = document.getElementById('responseMessage');

            sendButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch('/api/receive-message', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: 'hi'
                    });
                    const text = await response.text();
                    responseMessage.textContent = text;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error sending message:', error);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the app.py code:

```
    from flask import Flask, request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/api/receive-message', methods=['POST'])
    def receive_message():
        data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
        if data == 'hi':
            return 'I got it'
        else:
            return 'Message not recognized'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried to run my html file through a web server; however, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install something called CORS

if you want to know more about cors read this : https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/cross-origin-resource-sharing/

but how to fix your problem?
first download flask-cors package with this command : `pip install flask-cors` or with this command : `py -m pip install flask-cors`

then use it like this :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```